# Damager is called 1 to 3 times when opening a document

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jface

I have created an own editor for Eclipse that is based on the standard TextEditor class.
For this editor I have implemented several own damager/repairer classes that are implementing the ITokenScanner interface.
Now I found out accidentially that these damagesr are sometimes executed more then once when a document is loaded. After some debugging I found out what happens:

- the first time the document is parsed happens when directly after the file has loaded and before it is visible in the editor
- the second parser call happens only if the document has markers; then the AnnotationPainter executes the invalidTextPresentation method for the whole document and everything gets parsed again
- depending on the content of the file there may be collapsible regions; if there are regions the damager/repairers will be executed again

This means if the document has no markers and not collapsible region it will be only parsed before it gets visible. If there are markers or collapsible regions it will parsed again one resp. two times.
For small files this not a problem but for large files this may be disturbing.

Is there any chance to reduce the number of parser calls?